# can't resolve error "object not found" while read and displaying data on same page

Tags: php

I am new in php tried to write script that read and display data on same page.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$fnameErr = $passErr = "";
$fname = $password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passErr = "Password is required";
  } else {
    $password = $_POST["password"];
  }
}
?>
<p><span class="error">Field Required</span></p>
<form method="post" action="assignment.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail:<input type="text" name="password">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

After running it on web browser it display an error.

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12
```

Comment: Is your file named 'assignment.php'?

Comment: Yes 'assignment.php'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this program you just creating a form and not specifying any script that display data.
just simply write this script where form creation ends.

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Data:</h2>";
echo $fname;
echo "<br>";
echo $password;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your form action - by default the form action is set to the **current page**

You can test this by adding this into your current .php file (above everything else):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        echo '<pre>'. print_r($_POST, 1) .'</pre>';
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

You'll notice on initial load, the $_POST array won't dump out to the screen. Fill out the form and it will "refresh", posting the input value into the $_POST data with the key foo. This is now shown on the page.